# HP Infiniband HCA on Fujitsu Motherboard

Tags: installation, hp, infiniband

I am building a 2 node cluster using node-to-node Infiniband connection.

I have HP InfiniBand FDR/Ethernet 10/40Gb 2-port 544FLR-QSFP (P/N : 649282-B21) and Fujitsu D3118-A22 GS-2 Mainboard with dual Xeon E5-2690s and Ubuntu 16.04.4.

The problem is that I cannot find the HCAs using lspci. I was wondering if it's due to hardware compatibility or am I missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The HP 44FLR-QSFP is based on the Mellanox ConnectX-3 VPI. Havnt worked with the HP version, but you should probably be able to to use the Mellanox tools to check the HCA board.  See [this link](https://www.mellanox.com/page/management_tools?ssn=kgobdlapd7av8ksnoqlha7ok57)

Try the mstflint, mstconfig etc
Check the documents under "Mellanox Inbox Drivers" and the release notes for Your linux distro.

- setting the mode of the VPI hca/NIC to IB
- Loading of the IB kernel drivers
- install the OpenSM in one of the nodes

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. There is one thing though. The HP card has something called FlexibleLOM. Mechanically it fits in the PCIEx8 but the jury is still out on whether they have electrical compatibility.

Comment: oh dear!  that's out of my jurisdiction I'm afraid.